# router.post fail to post

Tags: javascript, html, web

```
    router.get("/createOrder/:id", async (req, res) => {
    let id = req.params.id;
    let data = {
        title: `Skapa order för kund id ${id}`,
        KId: id
    };
    data.res = await eshop.createOrder(id);
    res.render("eshop/createOrder", data);
});

router.post("/eshop/createOrder/:id", urlencodedParser, async (req, res) => {
    let id = req.params.id;
    console.log(id);
    await eshop.addProductToOrder(req.body.produktid, req.body.antal, id);
    res.redirect("/eshop/product");
});

    <%- include("header", {title: title}); %>

<h1>Create order</h1>


<pre><%#= JSON.stringify(res, null, 4) %></pre>

<form class="label-left" method="post" action="/eshop/createOrder/1">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Create order</legend>

    <label for="produktid">Produktid</label>
    <input id="produktid" type="text" name="produktid">

    <label for="antal">Antal</label>
    <input id="antal" type="number" name="antal">

    <input type="submit" name="doit" value="Create">
</fieldset>
</form>

<%- include("footer"); %>
```

Okay so basically for som reason Im getting "Cannot POST /eshop/createOrder/1" when i click on the Create button. I really have no clue what could be causing this, does anyone know? As far as I can tell the POST should be fine

Answer (score 0):

It's look like a nodeJS project with express and EJS.

Can you show us the app.js?

If your code really look like that, you cannot call the route inside the .ejs/.html. It's a mix between client side and server side.

Can you show us, the structure of your code?

I would recommend to read this : https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

Comment: what do you mean app.js?

Comment: What is your project look like? Is that a nodeJS project?

Comment: Yes, the thing is I have other post functions that work, its just this one that wont work

Comment: Can you show us, the error you're getting? And you server? It will help!